# getting a Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:]

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard

i know you've seen this error before and I find a lot of anwsers in stackoverflow about that! but I tried every single solution that I found and I still have the same problem !!

My problem is the same that in :" Assertion error when using pushViewController to a TableViewController "problem anwserd on stack over flow.
I'm working in this project right now and I have to modify an existing code that is using StoryBoard. I'm pushing my tableview programmatically instead of using story board but my program crash because of a cell problem I tired to use :

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    // or whatever cell initialisation method you have / created
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

switch (indexPath.section) {
    case PARUTIONSDETAILS_INFORMATION_INDEX:
    {
        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case PARUTIONSDETAILS_INFORMATION_INDEX_COVER:
              cell = [self tableView:tableView coverCellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                break;
            case PARUTIONSDETAILS_INFORMATION_INDEX_LIKES:
              cell = [self tableView:tableView likesCellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                break;
    .....
    return cell `
 i}
```

but i still have  Assertion failure in `-[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2380.17/UITableView.m:5471`. How can I fix it whithout changing the nib or xib and by just changing the code !!

Thank you for helping me !

Comment: can you post the complete `cellforrowatindexpath` code?

Comment: `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell"; UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil){cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];}
switch (indexPath.section) {
case PARUTIONSDETAILS_INFORMATION_INDEX:{
switch (indexPath.row) {
case PARUTIONSDETAILS_INFORMATION_INDEX_COVER:
cell = [self tableView:tableView coverCellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];brea...
return cell;
}

`

Comment: i can't put all the code it's too long and i'm not allowed to do it !it's a lot of swtch case like this one  `
            switch (indexPath.row) {
                case PARUTIONSDETAILS_INFORMATION_INDEX_COVER:
                  cell = [self tableView:tableView coverCellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                    break;
                case PARUTIONSDETAILS_INFORMATION_INDEX_LIKES:
                  cell = [self tableView:tableView likesCellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                    break;
                case PARUTIONSDETAILS_INFORMATION_INDEX_STOCK:
    
                
`

Comment: AssertionFailure usually includes some text explaining why the error was raised.  Edit your question to include the ENTIRE (copy/paste) text of the error message.  Also, edit your text to include cellForRowAtIndexPath -- don't put large blocks of code in comments.

Comment: The code you have added to your question differs from the code you had in your comment. Specifically there is a } missing in your question that closes the if cell == nil. This is in your comment and is significant because if it is missing then all the code that sets your cell will be skipped and you may get an incorrect cell. Also your code allocates or accessed a cell of reuse type "cell" but then proceeds to throw it away and assign cell based on the return of a number of other methods in your switch statement.  You should post at least one of those methods as an example

Comment: the code that i addedd in the comment is just the rest of my text, to answer the question of **Hot licks** i didn't get text explanation when the errors raised i just get an : _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2380.17/UITableView.m:5471 and to answer **Paulw11** i just thaught it was beacause the name of my cell didn't match the name of the cell in stroryBoard so i changed it, i don't have the same error but it still doesn't work !i even added a registerNib on the viewdidload but it still crashes and i got a SIGABT right in dequeueReusable